# Update Android Studio Giraffe, but it does not recognize my project as an app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, f#-giraffe

Good with control, it installs the latest version of Android studio Giraffe but it does not recognize my Android project. Nor does Android view icon appear as.

[image]

I hope I can compile and with the play icon and test in the emulator

Answer (score 1):

Click on Add your configuration and then in the run/debug configurations dialog press the + icon in the upper left corner, then select the (Android App) and then in the general tab, select your module, finally press ok and Let Android Studio start building your project, then the run icon will be activated and you can run your project

[image]